# How to remove square brackets from List results Groovy?

Tags: mysql, groovy

I have a query, the results of which I am adding to a list.
These results are being passed into another query using $systemTypeQueryResults

The value still has the square brackets around it which is causing the query to fail. My question is how to remove the square brackets in Groovy. If it helps the values are all integers. The population of the list works as follows:

```
String systemTypeQuery ="SELECT id from system_type where type = '${systemType}';"
    def systemTypeQueryResults = []
    ticketerDb.eachRow(systemTypeQuery) {
      systemTypeQueryResults << it.id
    }
```

When these results are used in a further query they display as follows: [1]
I would like to know how to remove these square brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString()` on a list object produces the string result with the brackets, to avoid the brackets you can use [join](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String)) on the list object as follows:

```
String systemTypeQuery ="SELECT id from system_type where type = '${systemType}';"
def systemTypeQueryResults = []
ticketerDb.eachRow(systemTypeQuery) {
  systemTypeQueryResults << it.id
}
def queryWithoutBrackets = systemTypeQueryResults.join(",");
```

This way you have a string with your results separated by commas which you can pass to your next query.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, that works great. It's essentially the opposite of split.

Comment: @MarieMurphy yes, like in javascript, nice to help you `:)`.